# Is it best practice in angular to wrap $rootScope broadcast and on in its own function?

Tags: angularjs

My angularjs application depends heavily on $rootScope.$on and $rootScope.broadcast. Does it make any sense to have the $rootScope.broadcast be wrapped in its own factory as opposed to calling $rootScope.broadcast directly?
I can see the benefits of having the subscribing $on being in its own factory such that you don't have to do $rootScope.$on, though I am not sure about the broadcast.

Different directives listen on different events on the $rootScope in my case, and not everything is used. DirectiveA has its own events, DirectiveB may have an overlapping set, DirectiveC may have events completely different from DirectiveA and B. The post seems to suggest putting all $rootScope events into a single service/"CoreReactorChannel" as the article below describes.

What prompted the question was reading this article:
http://eburley.github.io/2013/01/31/angularjs-watch-pub-sub-best-practices.html

It also bothers me that the function CoreChannelReactor appears to be "global".

At the bottom: "Best practices around pub/sub:" they show essentially all the on and broadcast code that is directly tied to $rootscope in its own service/factory.

Does this design pattern have any benefits in performance or practice over injecting $rootScope  directly into multiple services, directives, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "Best practice" in this case, but that's what we do here.
Ours is called EventBus, and it supports a few extra things like having different event channels to avoid collisions in custom events and logging events that are broadcast when there are no listeners.

In short, it can be useful, and I recommend it.

Another advantage of having this kind of abstraction is you can change the implementation of your events system more easily when it's all centralized.
For example, I recommend using $rootScope.$emit rather than $rootScope.$broadcast. That way, the even doesn't have to cascade down the $scope chain to all $scopes. It only cares about the ones listening at the $rootScope level.

Comment: Might you clarify on what you mean by supporting "different event channels"? I am not sure about the $rootScope.$emit. As based on the article, it looks like listening on "$scope" instead of "$rootScope" is better in case the directive is destroyed, in which the $scope would go away as opposed to hanging everything on $rootScope.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you might be right. I'm going to check our EventBus code in the morning to make sure we're not doing anything like that. But hey, if we are then it's basically a one-line change to fix it everywhere, thanks to abstraction :D

Comment: An Event channel allows you to send events with the same name but only send it to any listener on a specific channel. It helps to avoid unintended consequences of giving events the same or too-similar names. Each app feature could have a separate channel. A `'ProductsUpdated'` event might mean different things if it's broadcast on the `'HeaderView'` channel, vs the `'MainView'` channel. You could also listen to groups of channels or events, or broadcast a global event that ever channel hears (e.g. a global `'ProductsUpdated'` event could trigger ALL THE THINGS).

Comment: (I come from an event-heavy bg, you might be able to tell :D )

Comment: What I am concerned about having multiple channels is the requirement to inject multiple things per directive. Say I have a directive that listens for everything, I have to inject 10 different "ChannelAEventBus", "ChannelBEventBus", "ChannelCEventBus"? it seems it could get messy on the clientside.

Comment: In most cases the default channel is all you need (the one you get when you don't specify a particular instance). I don't want to give you the impression that the channels concept is always the best way to do it. If it were, standard event implementations would already use it.
The point to take away from all this is that by adding a layer of abstraction, you'll get more control, be able to make bugfixes and improvements more easily, and there isn't really much of a downside, if any.

Answer (score 1):

The major advantage of the pattern is consolidating your handling for a given event. It's basically combining an event source and handler into one object instead of having that logic spread out all over your app.